# Turn two arrays output into a table with dynamic updating in Powershell

Tags: powershell, dynamic, output

```
$array1 = @("device1", "device2", "device3")
$array2 = @("alive", "down", "alive")
```

I want to take the two arrays and output them in table format dynamically so I can change the color of the text depending on if the host is alive or down. I can currently do this, but the drawbacks of the below method outputs everything at once, and I cannot color the lines:

```
$max = ($array1, $array2 | Measure-Object -Maximum -Property Count).Maximum    

(0..$max | `
Select-Object `
@{n="Count";e={"{0,3:N0}" -f $arraycount[$_]}},`
@{n="Device";e={$array1[$_]}},`
@{n="Status";e={$array2[$_]}} `
| Out-String).Trim()
```

Desired output:

```
Count Device  Status
----- ------  ------
  1   device1  alive
  2   device2  down
  3   device3  alive
```

Comment: Is it necessary for your inputs to be arrays? What is the source of the data? It would be much easier to deal with this in an object, json, or xml blob; even tab delimited text would be a better input format.

Comment: instead of the `Select-Object` & `Out-String`, try using `ForEach-Object` and `Write-Host` to write the lines in the colors you desire. [*grin*] you may also want to look into one of the `Write-Color` or `Out-Color` modules in the PSGallery.

Comment: **1.** Where the `$arraycount` object comes from?  **2.** I'd add  an extra property e.g. `@{n="Watch";e={if ($array2[$_] -ne 'alive') {'!!!'} else {''} }}` instead of color…

Comment: @RepeatDaily I am building the arrays by using the output of the Test-Connection command. So I could just not use an array. How would we make the output display in a table with tab delimited text?

Answer (score 0):

First off, might I suggest outputting as HTML if you want something colorful. Since you are generating objects, you could very well use those to create a table in HTML, and have that formatted however you want.

```
0..$max | `
Select-Object `
@{n="Count";e={"{0,3:N0}" -f $arraycount[$_]}},`
@{n="Device";e={$array1[$_]}},`
@{n="Status";e={$array2[$_]}} `
|ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Prop *
```

If you want to add a bit of formatting you can define that for the header:

```
$Header = @"
<style>
TABLE {border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-collapse: collapse;}
TH {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; background-color: grey;}
TD {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black;}
</style>
"@
```

Then once you convert it to HTML you can do a little replacing to add per-cell formatting for the cells that have 'alive' or 'down' in them:

```
ForEach-Object{$_ -replace '>alive<',' bgcolor="Green">alive<' -replace '>down<',' bgcolor="Red">down<'}|
```

Then output to a file, and invoke that file to bring it up in a browser. All together it would be something like:

```
$Header = @"
<style>
TABLE {border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-collapse: collapse;}
TH {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; background-color: grey;}
TD {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black;}
</style>
"@

0..($array1.Count-1) | 
    Select-Object @{n="Count";e={$_+1}}, @{n="Device";e={$array1[$_]}}, @{n="Status";e={$array2[$_]}}|
    ConvertTo-Html -as Table -Property * -Head $Header|
    %{$_ -replace '>alive<',' bgcolor="Green">alive<' -replace '>down<',' bgcolor="Red">down<'}|
    set-content C:\Temp\Report.htm

invoke-item c:\temp\Report.htm
```

That would create a very simple table (click 'Run code snippet' below to see table):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style>
TABLE {border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-collapse: collapse;}
TH {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; background-color: grey;}
TD {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black;}
</style>
</head><body>
<table>
<colgroup><col/><col/><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>Count</th><th>Device</th><th>Status</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>device1</td><td bgcolor="Green">alive</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>device2</td><td bgcolor="Red">down</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>device3</td><td bgcolor="Green">alive</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

Of coarse, if you want it all within PowerShell, you're stuck with either `Write-Host` or a module to output your color. What you have works fine, you can just split it on new lines and process each line. If you define your colors in a scriptblock beforehand it makes coloring each line fairly simple:

```
$array1 = @("device1", "device2", "device3")
$array2 = @("alive", "down", "alive")
$ThisColor={
Switch -RegEx ($_.trim().split(' ')[-1]){
    'alive' {'Green';continue}
    'down'  {'Red';continue}
    default {'White'}
}
}
(0..($array1.Count-1) | Select-Object @{n="Count";e={$_+1}}, @{n="Device";e={$array1[$_]}}, @{n="Status";e={$array2[$_]}} | Out-String).Trim() -split '[\r\n]+'|%{Write-host $_ -ForegroundColor $ThisColor.Invoke($_)}
```